# update statement with where clause on current value

Tags: mysql, innodb, acid

I am trying to execute an update statement to update the balance in my database table. This table simply stores the userId and currentBalance.
I am using mysql with InnoDB.

I was thinking that a query like -

```
update account a set a.BALANCE= a.BALANCE + WITHDRAW_AMOUNT where a.USER_ID = ?2 and a.BALANCE + WITHDRAW_AMOUNT > 0
```

This query is meant to deposit or withdraw money ( in the case of withdrawal the net balance should not dip below 0)

If say I have a user with id 2. His current balance is 500.
There are 2 requests coming to withdraw money concurrently -

Req 1 - 300

Req 2 - 400

Now I was thinking that when the rows are being selected to update using the where condition could that happen concurrently? From what I understand right now the execution of the update statement does acquire a lock on the rows.

If yes, then say Req1 acquires lock for the user with id 2 and Req2 goes into waiting for these rows. Then our balance will be updated to 200.

Now the balance is 200, so will Req 2 execute because the rows have been selected or will it not because the entire statement is executed again for Req 2 and the where clause returns false since WITHDRAW_AMOUNT+balance<0 now?

Comment: A property of databases is "isolation". That means concurrent transactions leaves the database in the same state that would have been obtained if the transactions were executed sequentially. There is no cause to worry. By the way, your SQL statement has **a.USER_ID = ?2**. Either the **?** or the **2** is extraneous.

Comment: Show us the SQL, _including_ the necessary `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.